# how bring some text to a line before?

Tags: python, file, text

I have a text file like this:

```
1156348 epsilon[998] B          1e-08                             
1156349 epsilon[999]B          1e-08                             
1156350 epsilon[1001]
                    B          1e-08                             
1156351 epsilon[1002]
                    B          1e-08                             
1156352 epsilon[1003]
                    B          1e-08
```

as you can see the last 3 rows are a little different than the first 2 ones. how I can bring those `B` to the above line like this:

```
1156348 epsilon[999] B          1e-08                             
1156349 epsilon[1000]B          1e-08                             
1156350 epsilon[1001]B          1e-08                             
1156351 epsilon[1002]B          1e-08                             
1156352 epsilon[1003]B          1e-08
```

The purpose is to get numbers for each row. This a part of a bigger file. I found all lines contains epsilon and then grab numbers `1e-08`. but since after index 1000 they are in. the next line I can't grab them.

```
a1=[]
f1 = open('/Users/naghmeh/Documents/skill_trend/optimization/typex2.txt', "r")
for line in f1:
    if "epsilon" in line: 
        a1.append(line)
f.close()
t=[float(s.split()[3]) for s in map(str.strip, a1)]
```

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail? What's the principle for the transformation - merge if there are too few fields, merge if the line is too short, merge if the first non-whitespace token is a B?

Comment: @tripleee I tried to use a for loop after index 1000, but I couldn't write a code for fixing lines.

Comment: You could use regular expression find and replace in any IDE. In python, `import re; d = open('file.txt').read(); d = re.sub('\n.*?B','B', d); open('file.txt', 'w').write(d)`

Comment: @tripleee please see the edit.

Comment: `f.close()` is a NameError, you mean `f1`; but using a `with open` context manager is more elegant and robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt would pick out only the lines with "epsilon" in them. Instead, you want to collect all lines, but append to the previous line if there is no "epsilon".

```py
a1 = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if "epsilon" in line:
            a1.append(line)
        else:
            a1[-1] += line
```

This glues the line to the end of the previous line (`a1[-1]`, i.e. the final element in `a1` so far) if it does not contain "epsilon", but otherwise copies your existing logic.

This would crash if the first line does not contain "epsilon", but I leave it to you to make it robust for your use case.

Probably avoid hardcoding complicated paths; look for a file in the current directory, or have the script accept the input file name as a command-line argument.